# What .join() method does in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Actually, I'm doing a script which removes row duplicates from an array. And it works properly, but I don't know why :) Here is a string of my code:

```
if (refValues[i].join() == uniqueAddrs[n].join())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`refValues` and `uniqueAddrs` are array variables, and join() method just concatenates all elements in these arrays to a string. This is a quick and dirty way to check string arrays for equality.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth  mentioning that .join() is actually a core Javascript method, not a Google Apps Specific one.

You can see the documentation here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Thanks Any option for "ignore_empty"?

Comment: nothing built in to Javascript (that I'm aware of), you'd have to filter out your empty elements before you do the join.